Can't connect to MongoDB ReplicaSet deployed on Kubernetes (ReplicaSetNoPrimary error)
I have a Kubernetes local cluster for my node.js backend application, divided into microservices. On a pod, I'm trying to start a MongoDB ReplicaSet with one node, in order to use transactions.
This project is for learning purposes only, so I just need a basic setup to get started.
To deploy the database, I configured a Dockerfile like so:
FROM mongo

COPY replica-init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.js

CMD ["mongod", "--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all"]

The file replica-init.js is just this single line of code: rs.initiate();
Then, I reference the image as instagram-clone/profile-mongo in the kubernetes yaml files:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: profile-mongo-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: profile-mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: profile-mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: profile-mongo
          image: instagram-clone/profile-mongo
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: profile-mongo-cluster-ip
spec:
  selector:
    app: profile-mongo
  ports:
    - name: profile-mongo
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017

Finally, in my index.js file I simply do:
try {
        await connect(process.env.LOCAL_DB_URL!);
        console.log("Successully connected to the database.");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Couldn't connect to the database.", e);
    }

The ReplicaSet starts correctly but the microservice throws the following error:
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/usr/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:909:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/usr/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:860:11)
    at init (/usr/app/src/server.ts:7:9) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(1) { '127.0.0.1:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'rs0',
    maxElectionId: new ObjectId('7fffffff0000000000000002'),
    maxSetVersion: 1,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

Plus, is it correct to see 127.0.0.1:27017 in the error? That's not the cluster-ip address the microservice is using to connect to the database.
Here's what I tried to do:

exposing the port 27017 in the Dockerfile
setting ssl: false in the mongoose connect function
adding this configuration in the replica-init.js file:

rs.initiate({
  _id: "rs0", 
  members: [
    { _id: 0, host: "profile-mongo-cluster-ip:27017" }
  ]
});

I'll link my GitHub repository, for more context. The branch I'm working on is profile/enabling-transactions: https://github.com/davideaprea/Instagram-backend-clone/tree/profile/enabling-transactions
All of the yaml files are inside the infra folder.

You need to wait till replicaSet is initiated. Try to add while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) { sleep(1000) } after the initiate command.

Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work. I updated the answer with the GitHub repository, in case you need the full picture.

I was able to solve this issue by simply setting directConnection: true in the connect function by mongoose, like so:
await connect(process.env.LOCAL_DB_URL!, {
            directConnection: true,
            replicaSet: "rs0",
        });


this is wrong, directConnection=true effectively breaks your replicaSet configuration

your error says that you have no primary at some point, then you should investigate it, ie what servers you have and why no primary is elected
